# Fast DNS lookup, fast ping, slow HTTP over Wi-Fi but fine over wired Ethernet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

`nslookup` is fast (including for addresses I’ve not looked up before) and `ping` is fast (~10ms) to a range of addresses. `curl google.com` can take two minutes to return anything, but once established connections seem to give fast download speeds.

This is on a home Wi-Fi network ([Compal CH7485E](https://www.comhem.se/blob/43590/3/manual-compal-ch7284e-data.pdf) model router, 2.4 and 5 GHz, 802.11b/g/n), affects some devices (Mac OS X, Android phone) but not others (Windows, Linux laptops), and seems not to be affected by a choice of Wi-Fi channel or frequency. Changing DNS servers, e.g. to Google DNS, doesn’t help. Wired connections seem to be fine.

What could cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior for this device. Unless there will be a firmware update, you just have to accept it or get your own device.